# Android Remote Debugging working but not showing localhost wordpress files

Tags: android, wordpress, wamp

Yesterday I set up my android (Galaxy Note 3) for Google's remote debugging. It all works great and I can view any online site and debug.

I set it up in mind to debug my wordpress sites (while I am still building/testing them) via my localhost which is made via wamp (windows 7 pc).

I can see my wampserver page on my phone when I go to 192.168.1.35 (ipv4 address) it loads all ok, but if I enter a wordpress site to view it, it only loads the text on the page, no images, no stylesheets or javascript files (http://192.168.1.35/wordpresssite). On my desktop I would normally enter http://localhost/wordpresssite to view it.

It says for each of the files that have not loaded in the developer tools remote debugging:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Is there an extra port or something I need to open so these files can be access via my phone and display the wordpress site correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Oh I solved it, I'm so silly.

I just had to change the directory for the wordpress file e.g.

Either via WordPress Dashboard > Settings > WordPress Address & Site Address so it now says: http://192.168.1.35/wordpresssite

or via wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://192.168.1.35/wordpresssite');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://192.168.1.35/wordpresssite');
```